# Trying to programmatically present contained View Controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

Using XCode 6.1 I am trying to roll my own View Controller containment with a custom menu... I am using the following function within my Main View Controller to present child view controllers:

```
var currentController: UIViewController?

// Function within main view controller class
func presentController(controller: UIViewController) {
    if currentController != controller {
        if currentController != nil {
            currentController!.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
            currentController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
            currentController!.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
        controller.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
        self.addChildViewController(controller)
        self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        currentController = controller
    }
}
```

When the app is initially run I use `self.presentController(firstViewController)` inside `viewDidAppear`, which works.

However, in my custom menu (using [REMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu)) outside of the Main View Controller, I'm trying to display the selected view controller like so: `MainViewController().presentController(secondViewController)`. When this runs the currentController gets removed (revealing the Main View Controller's view which is just a black background) but the new controller doesn't get loaded in.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `MainViewController` is the name of your main view controller's class, the following line probably does not do what you intend:

```
MainViewController().presentController(secondViewController)
```

The `MainViewController()` will instantiate a new copy of the main view controller. I assume you meant to get a reference to the existing controller, not instantiate a new one.

---

Unrelated to your problem at hand, but you should not call `willMoveToParentViewController` before calling `addChildViewController` (because it does that for you). You only need to call `didMoveToParentViewController` when you're done configuring the new controller's view. Thus:

```
func presentController(controller: UIViewController) {
    if currentController != controller {
        if currentController != nil {
            currentController!.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
            currentController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
            currentController!.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
        // controller.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
        self.addChildViewController(controller)
        self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        currentController = controller
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I ended up doing `let applicationController = MainApplicationController()` at the app entry point, then I was able to do `applicationController.presentController(viewController)` to change the current controller. Amazing. Thanks!